# String to datetime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string strdate="25/9/2014" here in dd/MM/yyyy format.I want to parse it in date time like below

```
DateTime dt;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
            {
                dt = DateTime.Parse(strDate);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

But it can not parse.Please help me.

Comment: Why you parse your string twice?

Comment: if try parse returns true - you already have dt and you dont need to Parse again ;)

Comment: You need to use the format `"dd/M/yyyy"`...

Answer (score 9):

Two things:

1: Your string format should be `"dd/M/yyyy"` (a double MM will require two month digits; a single M will allow 1 or 2 month digits).

2: You are parsing the date string twice.

Change your code to:

```
DateTime dt;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, "dd/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy"));
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Can't parse it.");
}
```

[EDIT] Changed the Console.WriteLine() so that it outputs in the specific "dd/M/yyyy" format rather than using the local system locale.

Comment: Thanks I have tried your code.It gives me 9/25/2014.But Here in my string 25 is the day ,9 is the month.

Comment: @Joydip That is just because the `Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());` (the .ToString() is implied) is defaulting to "mm/dd/yyyy" format.  If you change it to `Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy"));` it should display as you expect.

Comment: @WyattEarp Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString()); isn't exactly "defaulting" to  "mm/dd/yyyy" - the result depends on your CurrentCulture (in this case it seems to be en-US)

Comment: @Arie In this case it is, that's all I meant.  You are correct though.

Comment: @WyattEarp I'm just overreacting because of my past mistakes :) There were a few cases when the difference between "default" and "localized" bit me hard (parsing numbers and dates, sorting lists, comparing strings, reading from serial ports...)

Answer (score 2):

`TryParseExact` needs to match exactly.

In your case try `dd/M/yyyy` as your input is

```
25/9/2014
dd/M/yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `"dd/MM/yyyy"` to `"dd/M/yyyy"`

because

`TryParseExact` looks for **Exact Match**